# How to send image present in angular assets folder in angular project to backend?

Tags: angular, typescript, file

[Asset image that I want to send to backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rfnI.png)

How to send image to backend that I already have in my anuglar project, I don't want to upload from html.

This is the code I have written, but i doesn't work!!

```
fileToUpload: File = new File(['assets/layout/images/register_user.png'], 'register_user.png');

private submitRegistration(){
 this.registerUser.registerUser(this.fileToUpload, this.registerForm.value).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: You can use the httpclient to get the image from the assets folder and then use that response to post the image to your backend.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but this seems to be a misunderstanding. Angular asset files will be `server files` once you built and deployed your app. No need to upload them ... except if the upload server is a different one

Comment: @devnull69 I suspect he wants to download the assets from the angular 'server' and upload them to an api.

Answer (score 1):

You have to load it using the http client.
The simplest solution would be:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

constructor(http: HttpClient) {
  const fileName = 'register_user.png';
  const path = '/assets/layout/images/' + fileName;
  const file$ = http.get(path, { responseType: 'blob' })
        .pipe(map(blob => new File([blob], fileName)));

  file$.subscribe(file => /*do something with file*/);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the HttpClient to fetch the image as a blob:

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

getImageBlob(): Observable<Blob> {
  return this.httpClient.get('assets/layout/images/register_user.png', { responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

image into a Blob or File object

```
blobToFile(blob: Blob, fileName: string): File {
  const b: any = blob;
  b.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
  b.name = fileName;
  return <File>blob;
}
```

Send the Blob or File object to your backend

```
submitRegistration() {
  this.getImageBlob().subscribe(blob => {
    const imageFile = this.blobToFile(blob, 'register_user.png');
    
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', imageFile, imageFile.name);
    formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(this.registerForm.value));
    
    this.registerUser.registerUser(formData).subscribe(/*...*/);
  });
}
```